# Is play effectively the same with 1 player, multiple runners?

Tags: shadowrun-crossfire

The rules say

> Runners are not allowed to show other runners what cards they have in their hand, but they can verbally discuss anything they like in order to form an effective plan as a team. To ensure a fun play experience for everyone, try to respect the other runners’ wishes about the level of advice they wish to receive.

This sounds like the usual rule given in ally forming games where you can help but may deceive people as well (like settlers), the rule being there to protect people from insisting you ‘prove’ your claim.  I find it odd here as an explicit rule in a fully cooperative game.

In any case, would the fact that this really doesn't prevent players from simply telling each other what they have mean that it's viable as a game where one player plays many runners (instead of the usual player playing one runner and having extra roles)?  This could be 2 players playing 4 runners or 1 player playing 4 runners, or even, for instance, 1 player playing 3 runners where one has an extra role.  This question is of course not so much asking whether it "can be played" but more whether it is effectively the same as the normal game.